# Mysql Server does not require password to access and edit databases

Tags: mysql, ubuntu

Currently running Ubuntu **18.04.2** and have a freshly installed MySQL server 5.7.26-0ubuntu0.18.04.1 running on my server. My problem is that when I connect to mysql through `mysql -u root -p` the password I set up through Secure Setup works but then if I type in any random string then that works also. Which leads me to think that it did not work. Additionally, I can login to the mysql server through `mysql` and `mysql -u root`.

Comment: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-reset-your-mysql-or-mariadb-root-password-on-ubuntu-18-04

Comment: Check your `my.cnf` for the lines `user=root` and `password=whatever`  --  If they are there .. .Delete them and restart MySQL